# focus() is not working in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to focus on an input element using javascript. This is the html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input:focus {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

  <form>
    First name: <input id="abc" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

When I manually click using the mouse, I can see the yellow background. But when I run the code $('#abc').focus() or document.getElementById('abc').focus() I don't see the yellow background. How to simulate the mouse focus using javascript?

Comment: your code works, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/1n5o4qkf/) I can not reproduce the issue

Comment: the code is working, try to check if you are not having any syntax error in javascript or namespacing the path for js file

Comment: If this is all the code then there's no jQuery included?

Comment: The problem is likely related to when the JavaScript code runs. For example, that JSFiddle link is running the code `onLoad`. How are you running your code?

Comment: If you provide your javascript code too, we can find out where the problem is

Comment: I was typing the code in the console. That is why it didn't work. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but accessing the input element using `document.getElementById('abc').focus()`, I am able to see the yellow background.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('abc');

input.focus();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input:focus {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

  <form>
    First name: <input id="abc" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just FYI 'it works, there's something else wrong' should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it working.
Hope it helps.

```js
$("#boton").click(function() {
  $("#abc").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input:focus {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

  <form>
    First name: <input id="abc" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  </form>
  <button id="boton"> Click Me to focus
</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('abc').focus();` will work if you put this line in `<script>` in head section of heml.

Or if you want to do it with jQuery then you need to put that code in document.ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#abc').focus();
});
```

Comment: @freedomn-m, can you tell me how ?

Comment: Ok.1 If you put that script in the `head`, it will run before the body has been generated (which is why we use doc.ready in jquery).  So 1 won't work as the `#abc` element won't yet exist.  2. You don't *need* to put jquery code in doc.ready, it will, as per 1, run when it occurs in the page.  If you put just `$('#abc').focus()` (no doc ready) at the end of the body, it will still work.  We use doc.ready so that the code is not dependent on its location within the body.